# How can I re-send an attachment from a message?

Tags: discord.js

So, what I want to do is something like this:

User: sends a command like this: mybot!announce @mention (message) (Attachs image)

Bot: gets the mention, message & attachment from the message, and deletes it. Then resends the message in an embed (see picture).

I managed to do everything else but I can't get the attachment & re-send it in the embed. Please, help :p
[image: Here is what the bot actually does.]

Here is the code I actually have, in case you need it:

```js
if (command === 'announce')
      {
        
        var mention = args[0];

        if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send('You need to mention someone!');

        var actualMention = null;

        if (mention === '@everyone')
        {
            actualMention = message.mentions.members.every();
        }
        else
        {
            actualMention = message.mentions.members.first();
        }

        var messageAnnouncement = args.slice(1).join(" ");

        if (msgAnnouncement === null) return message.channel.send('You need to put the announcement itself!');

        var imageAttachments = message.attachments;

        const anunouncementEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor('YPBot - Announcement')
        .setTitle(message.author.tag + ' made an announcement')
        .setDescription('Mentioning: ' + mention + '\n\n' + 
        msgAnnouncement)
        .setThumbnail(imageAttachments[0]);

        message.channel.send(anunouncementEmbed);

      }
```

Hope I explained myself well. In case I didn't, feel free to ask anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Message#attachments` actually returns a `Collection`, so if you want the first element you need `Collection#first()`. From there you can access the `MessageAttachment#url` property.

```js
.setThumbnail(imageAttachments.first().url);
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!
Now I'll just have to wait 5 mins so I can mark this as correct :p